# Puppet - Install module dependencies for non forge modules

Tags: module, puppet, forge

I have some puppet module, which is not in the forge and I am not interested to put it there. The module has all it's dependencies written down in the `metadata.json` and for the installation I usually just clone the module from its git repo directly into `/etc/puppet/modules/`.

When I now call `puppet module list` the missing modules are listed, for example like this:

```
Warning: Missing dependency 'puppetlabs-apt':
  '<name>' (v0.0.0) requires 'puppetlabs-apt' (>= 0.0.0)
Warning: Missing dependency 'puppetlabs-stdlib':
  '<name>' (v0.0.0) requires 'puppetlabs-stdlib' (>= 0.0.0)
Warning: Missing dependency 'puppetlabs-vcsrepo':
```

Is there anyway to let puppet install the dependencies for non-forge modules, despite the manual way by installing it with `puppet module install ...` ?

Answer (score 4):

You need `librarian-puppet`. With it you can easily manage the modules and its dependencies.

> Introduction
>
> Librarian-puppet is a bundler for your puppet infrastructure. You can use librarian-puppet to manage the puppet modules your infrastructure depends on, whether the modules come from the Puppet Forge, Git repositories or just a path.

You can download it from here [librarian-puppet](https://github.com/rodjek/librarian-puppet)